# How can I edit/remove Applications Menu categories in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I'm currently running Gnome 3 on Arch Linux, and need to change the categories (Favorites, Accesories, Internet, etc.) inside the [Applications Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/). How can I do this? I know that Kali Linux uses a modified applications menu to categorize various tools, and I would prefer to customize the applications menu like they managed to do, rather than using the default categories.

Comment: I don't use that extension but here's how to [customize categories](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/AppFolders) with plain gnome-shell. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the file containing all the menu items. It's located here: `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/kali-applications.menu`